# Who are Upa Brahmins?

Tags: scripture, dharma

Came across this verse in Jatibhaskar By Jwala Misra.It mentions Kayasthan as one of the types of Upabrahmins,who were Upbrahmins ? And who does this Kayasthan refer to ?[image][image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is in English

Comment: @swami reference is in sanskrit/hindi. Question clearly details in English.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda show me the rules of HSE which states this question to be closed

Comment: @swami  Why should it be closed ? I have explicitly mentioned what I want to know in English. The snippet in Sanskrit Hindi is just for reference.